GLM with clustered SE or GLMER
I'm doing an experiment of behavioral economics with 113 subjects that each answered to 6 questions randomly picked out of 10. My dependent variable is binary (Error=0 or Error=1) and I'm using a logistic regression. I don't know what to chose between GMLER with individuals random effects or GLM and then clustering SE at the individual level. I thought both would control for intra-individual correlation + GMLER adds also inter-individual variability. I tried both models but I get very different results and I'm unsure on how to interpret it and which model to chose.... Especially I don't really understand why all my coefficient are significant in GMLER but not in GLM. Does it mean that the random effects captured part of the unexplained variance? And hence that GMLER is a better model? It feels like my p-values are "too-good to be true".... thanks for your help
I did two logistic regressions using GLM (up) and GLMER (down) and compared the results. I get very different standards errors and p-values...Which one should I trust?
    # glm
model2 <- glm(Error ~ Complexity + Response_time +Response_time:Complexity, family = binomial("logit"), data = B)
clustered_se2 <- coeftest(model2, vcov. = vcovCR(model2, cluster = B$Individual, type = "CR2"))
p_values2 <- clustered_se2[, 4]


# glmer
model <- glmer(Error ~ Complexity + Response_time +Response_time:Complexity+ (1 | Individual), family = binomial("logit"), data = B)

Here are the results:



Welcome to CV. You are likely to get a better answer if you edit your post and paste the model results, in the same way you did with the model formulae…. Just delimit the results with 3 backticks: ‘’’

According to the results you posted, the generalised linear mixed model (glmm) has not converged, which may explain the large departure of the standard errors, especially for ‘complexity’ from that of the GLM model.

Does that mean that the GLM model should be preferred? Does it provide more reliable results?

I would spend a bit more time trying to get the GLMM model to converge. Ben Bolker's GLMM FAQ is a great resource for such problems,  and you can try different packages - one I would recommend is GLMMadaptive which often can fit models thatglmer can't. If none of that works, then yes, the GLM model would be preferable.
